# how to set interceptor to class with spring annotations?

Tags: java, annotations, interceptor, spring-4

I am using Spring 4 and i want to implement my interceptor which is:

```
public class MyInterceptor
    implements MethodBeforeAdvice {
    @Override
    public void before(Method method, Object[] args, Object target) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Intercepting..." + method.getName());
    }
}
```

So i want that some methods (or all of them if this is not possible) from my class `ClientService` be intercepted by these `MyInterceptor`. So, to be clear, this is my `ClientService` class:

```
@Service
public class ClientService{
     public void method1(){}
     public void method2(){}
}
```

I want to set this class the `MyInterceptor` to intercept `method1` or `method2` or both of them. And i want to do it with annotations. I cannot find the solution in doc. Do you know how to do it? Thanks

Comment: You can use [Handle Interceptor Adapter Class](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html) or [Handle Interceptor Interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html)

Comment: Maybe `aspect oriented programming` (AOP) is what you are searching for? Or do you want to intercept requests?

Comment: I am using aop ! thanks!